# Powershell command if folder is empty

Tags: powershell

I have a script that I run every morning to move some files. One of the folders that it's being moved from is often empty, and I am trying to find a way to have the script skip a command if a particular folder is empty. Here is the script:

```
#Variable values
$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
$d = $date.Day
$m = $date.Month
$y = $date.Year
$basefolder = "S:\Servicing Director Archive\OutputFiles"
$archivefolder = "S:\Servicing Director Archive\OutputFiles\Archive"
$array = @("AssetMgr", "AssetMgr_LoanAdmin", "LoanAdmin", "Management", "Monthly     Analytics", "Weekly Analytics")
$childitem = 

#Create variable containing month number and name
if ($m -eq 1) { $month = "01_January" }
if ($m -eq 2) { $month = "02_February" }
if ($m -eq 3) { $month = "03_March" }
if ($m -eq 4) { $month = "04_April" }
if ($m -eq 5) { $month = "05_May" }
if ($m -eq 6) { $month = "06_June" }
if ($m -eq 7) { $month = "07_July" }
if ($m -eq 8) { $month = "08_August" }
if ($m -eq 9) { $month = "09_September" }
if ($m -eq 10) { $month = "10_October" }
if ($m -eq 11) { $month = "11_November" }
if ($m -eq 12) { $month = "12_December" }

#Loop to move files
Foreach ($folder in $array)
{

#Create yearly folder
New-Item -Path $archivefolder\$folder -Name $y -ItemType "directory" -Force
$yearlyfolder = "$archivefolder\$folder\$y"

#Create monthly folder
New-Item -Path $yearlyfolder -name $month -ItemType "directory" -Force
$monthlyfolder = "$yearlyfolder\$month"

#Create daily folder
New-Item -Path $monthlyfolder -Name "$m.$d.$y" -ItemType "directory" -Force
$dailyfolder = "$monthlyfolder\$m.$d.$y"

#Copy files to daily folder
Move-Item $basefolder\$folder\*.* $dailyfolder -Force
Move-Item $basefolder\$folder\letters\*.* $dailyfolder -Force


}

#Sends completion email
$body = "This is a notification that the files have been moved. Please confirm."
$sender = "support@statebridgecompany.com"
$recipient = "dpatino@statebridgecompany.com, slinnenkamp@statebridgecompany.com,     hlinnenkamp@statebridgecompany.com, mbernal@statebridgecompany.com"
$smtp = "sbd600"
$subject = "Event Manager Output Files"
Send-MailMessage -body $body -From $sender -To $recipient -SmtpServer $smtp -Subject     $subject
```

So, what I want to happen is that if $basefolder\$array is empty, do not create $dailyfolder. I've looked at several threads about child-item, but I just can't make sense of them. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: since you have an answer for your question, I will throw in a freebie. You can replace all those if statements for the month with this: $m = $date.toString('MM_MMMM')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Create daily folder
if((gci $basefolder\$folder -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).count -ne 0) {
    New-Item -Path $monthlyfolder -Name "$m.$d.$y" -ItemType "directory" -Force
    $dailyfolder = "$monthlyfolder\$m.$d.$y"
}
```

**EDIT**
Cleaner version, use [Test-Path](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849776.aspx)

```
if(test-path $basefolder\$folder\*) {
    New-Item -Path $monthlyfolder -Name "$m.$d.$y" -ItemType "directory" -Force
    $dailyfolder = "$monthlyfolder\$m.$d.$y"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the length property of Get-ChildItem to determine if there are items in that folder, and proceed from there. Also, creating a folder returns a folder object, so you can just do things like:

```
If((Get-ChildItem $basefolder\$folder).length -gt 0){
    $dailyfolder = New-Item -Path $monthlyfolder -Name "$m.$d.$y" -ItemType "directory" -Force
}
```